# Passing loaded json to multiple functions

Tags: jquery, function

So I have a few functions working to do multiple things however I need to pass a json object through most of them. Reasons behind why is the need to use multiple jsons.

I load my json using a function...

```
function LoadJSON(path) {
    $.getJSON(path, function() { })
        .done(function(results) { return results; })
        .fail(function() { alert("Error loading content."); });
}
```

...from there I try to load it into a function...

```
function LoadScene(button) {
    ...
    LoadButtons(LoadJSON('js/content.json'), id); // id is determined in code
}
```

...finally I try to access the data in the function I need it the most...

```
function LoadButtons(obj, id) {
    alert(obj['data']);
}
```

... I have managed to load it directly without a load function or passing it from one function to another, however to make my code more efficient I need to  properly separate things.

However, it's not working: I have managed to use the ajax call inside the LoadButtons function, however when I separate it into three separate functions, it won't work and the alert returns "undefined".

Any reason why this wouldn't work how I am implementing it?

Comment: Is there a problem with what you've tried, or is this a vague throw-it-out-there query to see if this would/wouldn't work?

Comment: Its not working. I have managed to use the ajax call inside the LoadButtons function, however when I separate it into three separate functions, it wont work and the alert returns "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `LoadJSON` won't ever *return* json because it's async - so `LoadButtons(LoadJSON())` won't work.

You need to pass a callback function for the success, eg:

```
function LoadJSON(path, ondone) {
    $.getJSON(path, function() { })
        .done(function(results) { 
            if ($.isFunction(ondone)) ondone(results);
        })
        .fail(function() { alert("Error loading content."); });
}

function LoadDone(json)
{
    .. work with json
}

// call with:

LoadJSON('js/content.json', function(results) { LoadDone(results); })
//or
LoadJSON('js/content.json', LoadDone )
```

or use the promise directly:

```
function LoadJSON(path, ondone) {
    return $.getJSON(path, function() { })
        .fail(function() { alert("Error loading content."); });
}

LoadJSON('js/content.json')
    .done(function(results) {
        LoadDone(results)
    });
```

---

I wanted to add some detail regarding the `return` here:

```
function LoadJSON(path) {
    $.getJSON(path, function() { })
        .done(function(results) { return results; })
        .fail(function() { alert("Error loading content."); });
}
```

At first, I going to add that there's no `return` in LoadJSON so you'll always get null, but there "kind-of" is a return, it's in the `.done`.  But this is not part of LoadJSON as it occurs later (as `$.getJSON` is async)

So what happens is:

- LoadJSON starts
- Sees $.getJSON and goes: ok - I'll start the ajax call given the details you've provided and *returns immediately*
- LoadJSON exits (with no return statement, so returns *null*
- The ajax call then completes and hits the `.done` which just returns the result *back to the jquery ajax handler*

Comment: `// call with:

LoadJSON('js/content.json', function(results) { LoadDone(results); })` would call `LoadDone` immediately?

Comment: @guest271314 Why do you think that?  It's passing an anonymous function, not calling that function.  It's only called when the anon function is called with `ondone(results)`

Comment: _"It's passing an anonymous function, not calling that function."_ `()` invokes function?

Comment: I had some idea about ajax being async, however I admit I overlooked that fact.

Comment: @guest271314  The `()` (as in `(results)` are inside the function definition, this would call it immediately:  `function(results) { LoadDone(results); }()`

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, you are correct. Missed callback pattern at `, function(results) { LoadDone(results); }`

Comment: Thank you freedomn-m, using your example I figured out what I was doing wrong. Yes, I was suppose to return the actual ajax and then do a .done on LoadScene(). Managed to even reduce my code even more thanks to your answer. Though your right, the async was being performed incorrectly. Thank you for making me realize that.