# Get return value from jquery dialog box; asynchronously like alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
function confirmation(question) {
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $('<div></div>').html(question).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Confirmation',
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                defer.resolve("true"); //this text 'true' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "No": function() {
                defer.resolve("false"); //this text 'false' can be anything. But for this usage, it should be true or false.
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
    return defer.promise();
}

function ValidateForm() {
    alert("step2");
    var question = "Do you want to start a war?";
    confirmation(question).then(function(answer) {
        var ansbool = Boolean.parse(answer.toString());
        if(ansbool) {
            alert("this is obviously " + ansbool); //TRUE
            return true;
        }else{
            alert("and then there is " + ansbool); //FALSE
            return false;
        }
    });
    alert("step3"); // it gets call before dialog is open and return results on user selection Yes/No , i want to wait and return result true or false from this function
}

function calltovalidateform()
{
    alert("step1");
    var returnValue = ValidateForm(); // must return true or false value
    alert("step4" + returnValue); // returnValue is undefined.
    return returnValue;
}
```

above javascript code writes results in sequence of step1,step2,step3 & step4 alert message. i want the result of ValidateForm() which opens a dialog box with use of jquery model dialog box and returns value true or false asynchronously. without having to skip its confirmation result at run time. 
my requirement is to wait javascript until user provides a confimation yes or no in model dialog box.

Comment: The syntax is wrong here `function calltovalidateform();` the semicolon

Comment: `var returnValue = ValidateForm(); // must return true or false` - it won't it will return nothing because ValidateForm does not have a return statement.

Comment: See this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477951/passing-loaded-json-to-multiple-functions/37478219#37478219   That question is regarding $.loadJSON, but the same applies here with your async dialog

Comment: hi freedom-m , i have added return statement in ValidateForm() for result true or false base on user entry on screen dialog

Comment: @user1581768 no, you haven't.  You have a return inside the *promise* (the `.then`), which occurs **after** ValidateForm() has returned - there's no `return` in ValidateForm itself. See the 'more info' part of my previous answer (linked above).